# Bash Export Syntax Compatibility

Tags: bash, shell, compatibility, export

I often see commands written with the following syntax and I am curious if this is done for compatibility reasons:

*Snippet from Default .bash_profile on CentOS*

```
# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

I always prefer to write the more condensed version.  Is there any reason not to simply write this?

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

My guess is that older versions of the shell did not support this but could not find any details in searching.

Answer (score 0):

Both uses are equal. Separate export makes export explicit for clarity.